# Woocommerce product ID in url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to put a Woocommerce product ID in a URL, e.g.:

```
domain.com/product-category/id/product-title
```

The ID is the product's post ID, e.g. "12092". Automatically created by `WooCommerce` in `Wordpress`.

Can this be done in a way? Either easily through the `Wordpress` permalinks settings or in a different way through hacking my way into the files.

This nearly works:

```
<?php

add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ){
    return home_url( 'p/' . $post->ID );
} else {
    return $link;
}
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
add_rewrite_rule(
    'product/([0-9]+)?$',
    'index.php?post_type=product&p=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
}

?>
```

But the output is:

```
 domain.com/p/45
```

I'd like it to be:

```
 domain.com/p/45/title-of-the-post
```

Thanks!

Comment: Following link may help : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/33555#33555

Comment: Nearly there. It now shows:

http://example.com/product/142

But I'd like it to be as below (/p is my slug instead of /product)

http://example.com/p/142/ *title-of-post-or-product*

What would I need to change in the code from above's suggestion?

Comment: Please update your post with the code you've got working so far and someone will help.

Answer (score 8):

Why so complicated? Go to settings -> permalinks and click "Shop based URL" and save. Now you can see that the permalink structure in the "Custom structure". It should looks like this now:

```
/shop/%product_cat%/
```

Now add the post_id to the permalink setting like this:

```
/shop/%product_cat%/%post_id%/
```

Save it and go ahead.

Comment: You win my trophy for today. This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$post->post_name` to get the slug.

Use a more permissive regular expression to accept any url that ends with `/p/[id][anything]`

```
<?php

add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);
function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type != 'product' )
      return $link;

    return home_url( 'p/' . $post->ID . '/' . $post->post_name );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );
function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'p/([0-9]+)?.*?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&p=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

?>
```

You might need to 'reset' your permalinks in the settings menu for WordPress to accept the new rule.