# How to change WOOCOMMERCE products permalinks from product slug to product id?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need the product url to be not "www.example.com/shop/product-name" but like this "www.example.com/shop/2194"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce product ID in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769028/woocommerce-product-id-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change your permalink like this:
https://prnt.sc/D2Kr8oo3dje0

Comment: its working to default woocommerce posts, but not working to woocommerce products